# Lombok: RequiredArgsConstructor is not working

Tags: java, lombok

It seems that `@RequiredArgsConstructor` not working in the code below. Why is it?

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class User implements Serializable {

    private String username;

    /*public User(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }*/

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8043545738660721361L;
}
```

I get the error:

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The constructor User(String) is undefined
```

For some reason seems it does work for other domain class in which no constructor defined but instead used the `@RequiredArgsConstructor` annotation.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

According to [Documentation](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/RequiredArgsConstructor.html),
Required arguments are final fields and fields with constraints such as @NonNull.

You need to make username as  @NonNull

```
@NonNull private String username;
```

And you need to make them final too.

Comment: And `final` fields! Don't forget `final` fields. `final` fields often don't get much love (*repetition done on purpose* =D)

Comment: If you've already used final and/or @NonNull, try using a manual constructor to help narrow down the issue. A strategy for debugging can be found here: https://janac.medium.com/requiredargsconstructor-not-working-lombok-a1402e95aa6

Comment: Thanks, @JanacMeena , I had to create the constructor, and that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 15):

It's also worth noting for future readers that [@Data](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) also provides [@RequiredArgsConstructor](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor), so using both annotations isn't necessary :)

Comment: When you use `@Data` in combination with another constructor annotations like `@NoArgsConstructor` then `@RequiredArgsConstructor` won't be generated automatically.

Answer (score 5):

Did you installed Lombok plugin in IntelliJ?

If not then

`File -> Settings -> Plugins: Search for Lombok (CodeStream) version.`

Restart the IDE and it should be fixed.

**Double Check:**

- You have Lombok library installed using Maven or Gradle.
- Enabled `Annotation Processors` from IntelliJ IDE from `File -> Settings: Search for Annotation Processors`

Comment: I didn't know about plugin. Thanks, this works for me.

Answer (score 4):

> @RequiredArgsConstructor

```
> Generates a constructor with required arguments. Required arguments
 are final fields and fields with constraints such as @NonNull.
> Complete documentation is found at the project lombok features page
for @Constructor.
> Even though it is not listed, this annotation also has the
 *`onConstructor`* parameter. See the full documentation for more details.
```

Lombok library

To use the `@RequiredArgsConstructor`, the variable has to be `final` and it will create the values in constructor automatically

```
private final String username;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try changing project/module JDK to 1.8.

Project Structure -> Project Settings->Project SDK and Project Language Level

Comment: this helped indeed, even after switching back to 14 the error is gone

Answer (score 2):

The argument fields for @RequiredArgsConstructor annotation has to be `final`. So this fix will work:

```
private final String username;
```

The IDE IntelliJ makes the variable grey (inactive status) when `final` keyword missed, which is very helpful to detect this kind of mistake.