# @RequiredArgsConstructor does not generate constructor

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, java-8, lombok

I have a **Group class**:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String stateOrProvince;
    private String country;
    private String postalCode;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Event> event;

}
```

A GroupRepository interface:

```
public interface GroupRepository extends JpaRepository<Group, Long> {

    Group findByName(String name);
}
```

A Initializer class to load data:

```
@Component
public class Initializer implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final GroupRepository repository;

    public Initializer(GroupRepository groupRepository) {
        this.repository = groupRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Stream.of("Denver JUG", "Utah JUG", "Seattle JUG",
                "Richmond JUG").forEach(name ->
                repository.save(new Group(name)));
    }
}
```

**Specifications:**

1. IDE: Eclipse
2. Java: 1.8

Why I am getting an error on `repository.save(new Group(name)));` and how to resolve it?

**Error:** `The constructor Group(name) is undefined.`

**Note:** Although I am using lombok and added `@NotNull` on name field in Group class.

Comment: the answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671467/lombok-requiredargsconstructor-not-working) can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Lombok does not suport @NotNull, You need to make field final or use Lombok's @NonNull.